# Finding out the DLL file Service Reference is using

Tags: c#, wcf, web, reference, wcf-binding

I have a website that is attached to a web reference, eg ServiceReference1.

Now, I want to create a new website with using ServiceReference1 without using any GUI(VS or whatsoever). I just want to copy the files(xsd and svcinfo files) of ServiceReference1 from the App_WebReferences folder to the new website folder.

The thing is, how do I find out which DLL file is the ServiceReference1 referring to by using the xsd and svcinfo files?

I have tried using svcutil, but it can only download its metadata.

I am trying to build a standalone application that create a website and also copy web reference from other existing website. Then deploy the website to other servers. There for I need to know the running DLL that is on the existing website and copy it to the new website.

Comment: How do you invoke the web service? As far as I know, we could use the following command to generate the client proxy class which contains the CS file and the app.config so that we could invoke the web service.
svcutil.exe http://localhost:8008/Service1.svc?wsdl /directory:D:\

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The service was installed using runtime installer. So now I want to find back the DLL?

Comment: you could search for it under BIN/Obj folder. I don't think is is a good idea that trying to copy the DLL file directly to a new website. Generating and run Dll reply on the compiled environment/platform. I recommand that you use SVCUTIL.exe tool to regenerate the client proxy class and call the service.

Comment: yes. you are right. I think I probably got the whole idea wrong from the first place. The DLL is meant to be hosted by the server. The client don't need it. 

My Solution is just to copy the client files(*.xsd, *.wsdl) into my new website. And update the web.config file to do the bindings,that's it. The DLL is handled by another installer.

Comment: We know a question is answered (successfully) when there are one or more *answers* posted to it and you have (hopefully) accepted the one that answers your question. Self-answered questions are welcome here, but please familiarise yourself with how this site works.